# Seeing console output without console?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I'm making an application and would like to test the toString method I just made. I'm using Visual c++ 2008. Is there a way to see console output without having a console window? Such as in the Output panel?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into unit testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx), it will display the string in the output window when you run the program under VS++. Most other debuggers (and a number of other monitoring applications and such) can/will display such strings as well, but when you run the program without a debugger (or something similar) that output will simply be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

A clean option is to print out to file.

```
ofstream fout(test.txt);
fout << widget.toString() << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print to `stdout` or to `stderr` for a Windows application, you can still access the output through redirection.

For example:

```
foo.exe > file.txt
```

or if you have a [Windows version of `cat`](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), you can do:

```
foo.exe | cat
```

Comment: Upvote because I can use this to capture "stdout" from a RunDLL32 run of one of my exported functions..

Answer (score 0):

Add System.Diagnostics and you can use the Debug Classes static methods to write to the output window. ie

```
  Debug.Write("bleh");
  Debug.WriteLine("bleh");
```

and whatnot.